# Unable to delete a file

Tags: linux

An update has corrupted my system, I attempt a receipt and update of php5 error that you can not write `/usr/lib/php5/libexec`.

When I try to read this file, which I find is this:

```
root@host:/usr/lib/php5 # ls-la 
ls: can not access libexec: No such file or directory 
Total 16 
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 July 29 10:26. 
drwxr-xr-x 59 root root 12288 July 29 11:11 .. 
d????????? ? ? ? ? ? libexec
```

The libexec file apparently does not exist but if it exists, can not access it to delete or overwrite, the error is as follows:

```
root@host:/#rm libexec usr/lib/php5 
rm: can not remove libexec: No such file or directory
```

Therefore when performing update php5 can not replace this file.

It is the first time that happened to me, can anyone lend a hand?

Comment: Have you tried fsck?

Comment: What is your distribution/OS? The meaning of some of your sentences are very obscure. E.g. "I attempt a receipt and update of php5 error that you can not write /usr/lib/php5/libexec." Second, "The libexec file apparently does not exist but if it exists, can not access it to delete or overwrite, the error is as follows:" I think it is safe to say that file does not exist.

Comment: You can get the `?`s if you don't have `x` permission. Am wondering if you have SELinux or other enhanced security system enabled.

Comment: I note that the code that you included above, is not the code you ran. Can you please paste the real code that has the problem.

Comment: `/usr/lib/php5/libexec` should be a directory, right? So you can not remove it with just `rm` anyway. Oh, there's a d in "d?????????" - it's a directory, but looks broken indeed.

Comment: How did it corrupt your system? What happened, exactly?

Comment: I agree with Richard. I would suspect an SELINUX issue before jumping to a file corruption issue.  Since you did not post the OS, I cannot give you the exact command but generically run this "setenforce 0" then try again.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it looks like corruption. You should check that your drive is not failing. A failing drive could be causing your corruptions. Then fsck your drive and force a reinstall of new packages. If the drive is good, you may have to reinstall the OS if it is too corrupted where you can't install packages.